# How to get current last 5 row from the table

Tags: php, android, sql

**I have 13 row in my table**

```
id
13
12
11
10
9
8
9
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

**i want last 5 row which is id<10**

so i have implement

```
select * from emp where id<10 LIMIT 5 ORDER BY DESC;
```

**but it give me this output**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

**But i want**

```
9
8
7
6
5
```

Comment: select * from emp where id<10  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * from emp where id<10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @RohitKumar Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer works for you, you should accept it as an answer so that people may find it on the top.

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` goes after `ORDER BY`.  Your query should generate an error.  Try:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where id < 10
order by id desc
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this,

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE id < 10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```